# How to fix "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status" error in react app with nodejs api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I have been trying to do an api call (nodejs with express running on localhost) from a react app running in the browser over a local dev server (web-pack dev server). Everything was working well until I tried to call the api. They are both running on separate ports.

I have tried adding the cors headers (Recommended by MDN) to both the post call (from the app in browser) and to the response from the Nodejs API but neither of these solved the issue.

Code for the api call (in browser):

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'access-token': '',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
}

export default async () => {
  try {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      test: true,
    })
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/internal/provider/check_email_exist', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers,
      body,
    })
    console.log(response)
  } catch (e) {
    return e
  }
}
```

API Middleware (in nodejs):

```
// Verify All Requests
app.use(VerifyToken)

// Compress
app.use(compression())

// Helmet middlware
app.use(helmet())

// Body Parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false,
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

The expected result is to just give a 200 status code and respond with the data.

The actual output is:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:1337/internal/provider/check_email_exist 404 (Not Found)
```

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:1337/internal/provider/check_email_exist' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should come from the server, not the client. You can try using the `cors` module (`app.use(cors())`) to get this working, but I suggest you read up on CORS and how it is used to protect web browser users. It also looks like you haven't implemented a route for `/internal/provider/check_email_exist` which is why the request is failing in general.

Comment: The server you’re sending the request to must be configured to respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK success response. Right now, it’s responding with a 404 error to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request your browser is sending. So you don’t have the server properly CORS-enabled yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `webpack-dev-server` you can use the `proxy` option [DevServerProxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server#devserverproxy).

Your configuration will look like this:

```
// webpack.config.js
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/internal': 'http://localhost:1337'
    }
  }
```

Since I can't see your `express` routes on your question I'm speculating about the proxy route if your `API` lives on `/internal` endpoint then you should modify your React code like this:

```
const response = await fetch('/internal/provider/check_email_exist', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers,
   body,
})
```

As you can see I ommited the `https://localhost:1337` because the `proxy` option from `webpack-dev-server` will handle this and it will redirect to `http://localhost:1337`. Hope this will help you. Cheers, sigfried.

**EDIT**

As the comment on your question pointed out you should set the headers on your `express` server, not the client, for this task you can use the [cors-middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help if you face with preflight errors.

My full config:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware: proxy } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

...
const logLevel = 'info';
const ip = require('ip').address();

const proxyOptions = {
  xfwd: true,
  target,
  changeOrigin: true,
  logLevel,
  cookieDomainRewrite: {
    '*': 'localhost',
  },
  headers: {
    'X-Forwarded-For': ip,
    'X-Node': 'true',
  },
};

const backNginxApp = express();

backNginxApp.use(
  cors({
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
backNginxApp.use('/api', proxy(proxyOptions));
```

API: `const target = 'https://someapi.com'`

Local development running at: `http://localhost:3000`